# perl pgrep returning multiple pids

Tags: perl

I have some a perl code like this to get the pid of the process if it
existed. I wanted to know the return status of pgrep so I can find out if the pid is valid or not. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $pid=`pgrep -n -f \"akonadiserver\"`;
print "$? ";
chomp $pid;
print "Output1: $pid\n";
$pid=`pgrep -n -f \"akonadiserver\"`;
my $evalue=${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE};
chomp $pid;
print "Output2: $pid, $evalue\n";
```

But whenever I run it, I get the following:

```
0 Output1: 3054
Output2: 3056, 0
```

another run

```
0 Output1: 3059
Output2: 3061, 0
```

But in the system:

```
$ pgrep -n -f akonadiserver
1862
```

Several problems seen here:

1) The pid returned is changing all the time, most likely it is matching
the grep process itself.

2) I don't have a way to find out of the pid returned is valid or not. `$?` 
doesn't help.

How do I check the return status and how do I use pgrep properly in perl?

Comment: What do you mean by `"find out of the pid returned is valid or not"`? From the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) `"pgrep  looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout"`.. so any returned PID will be a running process..

Comment: As explained in the example above, the returned value that is supposed to be the pid is not correct. I get 3056, 3059 etc. whereas the actual pid of the process is 1862. So when it returned the different (wrong) pid, how do I check the status ? because obviously $? isn't working.

Comment: You cannot use the return value of `pgrep` to check for correct process.. The return value simply says if it found any process or not. If it finds one, two, three, or any positive number of processes, the return value will be zero. What you need to do is to check if there is something in the command line (of what you think is the correct process) that separates it from the processes that are not correct, or if there is some other caracteristics (like starting time) that could separate the correct from the other processes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `` `pgrep -n -f akonadiserver` `` from a Perl script, is equivalent to running `sh -c "pgrep -n -f akonadiserver"` from the terminal.

From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) :

> **qx/STRING/**:
>   A string which is (possibly) interpolated and then executed as a system command with /bin/sh or its equivalent.

The problem is that using the `-f` option with `pgrep` will match against the full command line used to invoke the process. This will also include the current `pgrep` command, since its command line will look like `sh -c "pgrep -n -f akonadiserver"` which will match the string `"akonadiserver"`. Since you also use the `-n` flag with `pgrep` it will only return the newest process that matches `"akonadiserver"` and this will most likely be the `pgrep` command itself (`sh -c "pgrep -n -f akonadiserver"`).. So that explains why you get the wrong process id.

It does not however explain why it still works from the terminal window. The reason is that from the terminal window, the `pgrep` command is run with `bash` and not `sh` (as from the Perl script), see this question for more information about the difference: [Difference between pgrep in sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772778/difference-between-pgrep-in-sh-and-bash). As a result, running `pgrep -f` from the terminal window will not include the `pgrep` command itself, and therefore it will work for your case.

To obtain a reliable result from Perl, you should use [`Proc::ProcessTable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Proc::ProcessTable;

my $pat = "akonadiserver";
my $pt = Proc::ProcessTable->new();
my @tab;
for my $p ( @{$pt->table} ){
    if ($p->cmndline =~ /\Q$pat\E/) {
        push @tab, {pid => $p->pid, start => $p->start};
    }
}

say $_->{pid} for (sort {$b->{start} <=> $a->{start}} @tab);
```

Comment: This is clean and explanation is spot on. I'm about to conclude with this question but Is there any way to do this without ProcessTable eg. with just sed,awk and pgrep ? Would a hacky way like reading the pid twice and verifying if they are same work in all case ?

Comment: Do you mean calling `awk` from within a Perl script? Why would like to avoid `Proc::ProcessTable`?

Comment: awk or sed or anything from within perl without having to install perl modules. In embedded environments, it might not be possible to perl modules other than the bare minimum.

Comment: You could try `perl -E '@a=grep {$_=~/akonadiserver/ && $_!~/pgrep/} qx{ps -eo pid,cmd --sort=start_time}; say @{[split " ", $a[-1]]}[0]'`

Comment: This one again returns the pid for Grep itself. http://pastebin.com/d3kdPuCv . Is it not possible to find this without using ProcessTable ?

Comment: Interesting, it seems to work here.. try to replace the last part: `say @{[split " ", $a[-1]]}[0]` with `say $a[-1]`, then you can see the actual name of the command also.. What command name do you get?

Comment: Ahhh.. I think I see a problem.. The command does not contain `pgrep` any more since we use `ps` now instead.. Try replace `pgrep` with `ps -eo`.. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, this helps with my issue. I think you answered the question using ProcessTable. I'll close this for now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that pgrep returns the pid of the newest (-n) child process started by the process you are looking for, at least that is what happens on my system.

I have always used ps for such things, how about:

```
my $pid = (split(" ",`ps -A | grep \"akonadiserver\"`))[0];
```

instead, or

```
my @pids = map{ $_ =~ /(\d+)/; $1 }split("\n", `ps -A | grep \"akonadiserver\"` );
print "mutiple instances: @pids\n" if @pids > 1;
print "pid: ".$pids[0]."\n" if @pids == 1;
```

to get all instances running into an array and then do what you want to with it.

Comment: In the first solution : [0]; what does this do ? if it returns the 0th entry of the list of processes, imagine what would happen if the process is not running, it will return the pid of the grep process and I am back at square one where I don't know if the pid returned is the pid of the running process or the pid of grep.

Comment: No it will not. The list will be empty, so the first element in an empty list is undef, you end up with undef in $pid. What else would you want? I am using your grep criteria. that is why ps -a | grep and not just ps -A. Did you even try it? Also, I highly doubt the first entry would be grep.

Comment: Ofcourse, I tried it. [link](http://pastebin.com/6Qry5ZTS). why would you doubt if the first entry would be grep when the process you've given is not running. The first entry then would be grep.

Comment: I doubt it because I tested it on my system and it worked fine, it has worked fine before, and the link you provide only says you call some text.txt which could be anything. Still, interesting explanation above:)