# Difference between pgrep in sh and bash

Tags: bash, grep, sh

Here is a test:

```
$ bash -c "pgrep -f novalidname"
$ sh -c "pgrep -f novalidname"
11202
```

Why is `pgrep` giving output when run from `sh`? (As far as I can see, there are no processes on my computer that is named `novalidname`)

Comment: May i ask what did you end up doing. figuring this out took quite some time for me. Specially that i was using popen() which internally uses only sh. so did you end up using bash instead of sh or were you able to find some cleaner way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a timing issue and `pgrep` finds itself, as you're issuing it with `-f` and `novalidname` is present in the command line. Try with `-l` to confirm.

Comment: Yes, seems like so.. For example this gives also output: `bash -c "sleep 1; pgrep -f novalidname"`

Comment: It's not a timing issue. It's a bash optimization, similar to Tail Call Optimization.

Comment: I suspect that on the OP's system `/bin/sh` is simply a link to `/bin/bash`. Then what?

Comment: @mustaccio: I suspect you are wrong about that :). My suspicion is based on the observed behaviour as revealed by the question (and which reproduces perfectly on a system I use.) And yours?

Answer (score 2):

The actual explanation:

1. Regardless of flags, `pgrep` *never* returns its own PID.
2. If you execute `bash -c` with a simple command, then bash will `exec` the command rather than creating a redundant subshell to execute it in. Consequently, `bash -c "pgrep -f blah"` will *replace* the `bash` process with a `pgrep` process. If that `pgrep` process is the only process whose command line includes `blah`, then `pgrep` will not display any PIDs (as per 1).
3. `dash` does not perform the above optimization. (`zsh` and `ksh` do.) So if on your system, `sh` is implemented with `dash`, then `sh -c "pgrep -f blah"` will result in two processes being executed -- the `sh` process and the `pgrep` child -- both of which contain `blah` in their command lines. `pgrep` will not report itself, but it will report its parent.

Comment: _"pgrep never returns its own PID"_ -- how can you be sure, without even knowing what OS we're dealing with?

Comment: @mustaccio: It is documented in the pgrep manpage. Regardless of OS, it is easy for a process to get its own PID, and so it is trivial for pgrep to eliminate it from the list. The fact that pgrep makes this guarantee is one of the reasons it is a much better tool than grepping the output of ps.

Answer (score 1):

That's one thing (finding itself because of delay) see also:

```
$ ps ax | grep novalidname
```

Here it usually shows as well. (on Ubuntu does for me. (under bash)

The other thing is what is /bin/sh bound to?

On most Linux distros /bin/sh is a soft link to default shell which is usually actually bash, but can be any other shell.

The time difference that causes grep/pgrep to show itself may be introduced by finding a soft link location (hm, odd) or some other shell is bound to /bin/sh which executes slightly different than bash, thus causing the delay needed for process to show in pgrep.

Also, bash will firstly try to source ~/.bashrc and load its history, while /bin/sh will do what will do. In .bashrc can be pgrep defined as alias in another way which may also affect the difference.

To see where /bin/sh points to do:

```
$ readlink -e /bin/sh
```

Or just run sh to see what will show up. :D